# How to send acknowledgment (Consumer) in RabbitMQ externally?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, delegates

I have an application where it sending message to RMQ broker as below:

```
 var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
               HostName = "localhost"
            };

            using (var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.QueueDeclare("demo",
                        durable:true,
                        exclusive:false,
                        autoDelete:false,
                        arguments:null);

                    Console.WriteLine("Click enters to send random case Id");
                    do
                    {
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        var message = new {CaseId = new Random().Next()};
                        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));

                        channel.BasicPublish("", "demo", null, body);
                        Console.WriteLine("Successfully send message.");
                    } while (true);

                }
            }
```

It successfully sent the message.

There is another app called the consumer app.

The code is below:

```
private void InitiateRabbitMq()
        {
            var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
                HostName = "localhost"
            };

            var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
            var channel = connection.CreateModel();

            MessageHandler messageReceiver = new MessageHandler(channel);
            channel.BasicConsume("demo", false, messageReceiver);

        }
```

The message handler is:

```
public class MessageHandler : DefaultBasicConsumer
    {
        private readonly IModel _channel;
        public MessageHandler(IModel channel)
        {
            _channel = channel;
        }

        public override async void HandleBasicDeliver(string consumerTag, ulong deliveryTag, bool redelivered, string exchange, string routingKey,
            IBasicProperties properties, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> body)
        {
            var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body.ToArray()));

            _processor.process(message);
        }


    }
```

Here is the process method parth which is another class:

```
client.BeginTransfer(transfer,
                                       HandleUploadProgressChanged,
                                       HandleUploadComplete,
                                       HandleUploadInterrupted,
                                       HandleUploadCancelled,
                                       3600,
                                       UploadFilesFinishedCallback);
```

Once begin transfer completed. It invoked **UploadFilesFinishedCallback** . I want to acknowledge in this method. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you Acknowledge message:

```
channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag, false);
```

So it means your Function "UploadFilesFinishedCallback" must have the deliveryTag

==> and this means that also your "process" function must have the deliveryTag (which currently gets only the message content)

solution:
add new parameter "deliveryTag" to function "process", and to function "UploadFilesFinishedCallback"

you can use it in the callback like this:

```
client.BeginTransfer(transfer,
               HandleUploadProgressChanged,
               HandleUploadComplete,
               HandleUploadInterrupted,
               HandleUploadCancelled,
               3600,
               () => { UploadFilesFinishedCallback(deliveryTag) });
```

(depends on the signature of the callback function)